# Trouble with foreach logic

Tags: powershell, veeam

I'm trying to get a list of all virtual machines in all of my Veeam backup jobs.  I wrote this

```
#Add Veeam snapin
Add-PSSnapin VeeamPSSnapin

#variables
$Masterlist = @()
$jobs = Get-VBRJob

foreach($job in $jobs) {

    $backupJobObjects = Get-VBRJobObject -Job $job 

    foreach($backupJobObject in $backupJobObjects) {
        $MyObject = New-Object PSObject -Property @{ Name = $backupJobObject.Name }
    }
    $Masterlist += $MyObject
} 

$Masterlist | sort-object -Property Name
```

but it only spits out data from one job (there are 5).  I assume this is because of some logic error in the foreach loop but I'm not seeing it.  Can anyone help?

Comment: move `$Masterlist += $MyObject` inside last foreach loop

Comment: `$Masterlist =  @( foreach($job in $jobs) { $backupJobObjects = Get-VBRJobObject -Job $job; foreach($backupJobObject in $backupJobObjects) { New-Object PSObject -Property @{ Name = $backupJobObject.Name } } } )`

Comment: That did it, thanks!

Comment: Post the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the per the comment from 4c74356b41

```
foreach($backupJobObject in $backupJobObjects) {
        $MyObject = New-Object PSObject -Property @{ Name = $backupJobObject.Name }
        $Masterlist += $MyObject    
}
```

Is how the last foreach loop should look